# Proving sets are equal with cardinality?

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that if |A1| = |A2| and |B1| = |B2| then |A1 x B1| = |A2 x B2|.

I'm assuming I have to prove that their is a bijection between the two sets but I'm not sure how to start

Comment: You know there is a bijection $f\colon A_1\to A_2$, and one $g\colon B_1\to B_2$. What would be a natural bijection from $A_1\times B_1$ to $A_2\times B_2$, then?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the bijection $h(x,y)=(f(x),g(y))$.

For any point $(a,b)$ in $A_2\times B_2$, we have some $x\in A_1$, $y\in B_1$ such that $f(x)=a,g(y)=b$ since $f$ and $g$ are surjections. Thus, $h(x,y)=(a,b)$ and we have that $h$ is a surjection.

Now, if $h(x,y)=h(x',y')$, then $f(x)=f(x')$ and $g(y)=g(y')$. However, both $f$ and $g$ are injections so $x=x'$ and $y=y'$. Thus, $h$ is an injection from $A_1\times B_1$ into $A_2\times B_2$.

Since $h$ is both a surjection and an injection, it is a bijection between those two sets. Thus, they have equal cardinality.

QED.